# How to set up a Docker Swarm cluster with overlay network mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I create a docker swarm cluster on 2 Linux machine, but when I use docker-compose up -d   to  start containers ,  some error has occurred.

This is my docker info:

```
Containers: 4
 Running: 4
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 28
Server Version: swarm/1.2.5
Role: primary
Strategy: spread
Filters: health, port, containerslots, dependency, affinity, constraint
Nodes: 2
 ozcluster01: 192.168.168.41:2375
  └ ID: CKCO:JGAA:PIOM:F4PL:6TIH:EQFY:KZ6X:B64Q:HRFH:FSTT:MLJT:BJUY
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 2 (2 Running, 0 Paused, 0 Stopped)
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 2
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 3.79 GiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=native-0.2, kernelversion=3.10.0-    327.13.1.el7.x86_64, operatingsystem=CentOS Linux 7 (Core),     storagedriver=devicemapper
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-11-04T02:05:08Z
  └ ServerVersion: 1.10.3
 ozcluster02: 192.168.168.42:2375
  └ ID: 73GR:6M7W:GMWD:D3DO:UASW:YHJ2:BTH6:DCO5:NJM6:SXPN:PXTY:3NHI
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 2 (2 Running, 0 Paused, 0 Stopped)
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 2
  └ Reserved Memory: 64 MiB / 3.79 GiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=native-0.2, kernelversion=3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64, operatingsystem=CentOS Linux 7 (Core), storagedriver=devicemapper
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-11-04T02:05:06Z
  └ ServerVersion: 1.10.3
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    ports:
     - "5672:5672"
     - "15672:15672"
    network_mode: "bridge"
  config-service:
    image: ozms/config-service
    ports:
     - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
     - ~/ozms/configs:/var/tmp/
     - ~/ozms/log:/log
    network_mode: "bridge"
    labels:
     - "affinity:image==ozms/config-service"
  eureka-service:
    image: ozms/eureka-service
    ports:
    - "8761:8761"
    volumes:
     - ~/ozms/log:/log
    links:
     - config-service
     - rabbitmq
    environment:
     - SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
    network_mode: "bridge"
```

after I exec `docker-compose up -d`  ， the service `rabbitmq`  and `config-service`  can be started up , but `eureka-service` caused an error:

```
[dannil@ozcluster01 ozms]$ docker-compose up -d
Creating ozms_config-service_1
Creating ozms_rabbitmq_1
Creating ozms_eureka-service_1
ERROR: Unable to find a node that satisfies the following conditions 
[port 8761 (Bridge mode)]
[available container slots]
[--link=ozms_config-service_1:config-service --link=ozms_config-service_1:config-service_1 --link=ozms_config-service_1:ozms_config-service_1 --link=ozms_rabbitmq_1:ozms_rabbitmq_1 --link=ozms_rabbitmq_1:rabbitmq --link=ozms_rabbitmq_1:rabbitmq_1]
```

And I exec `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                           NAMES
871afc8e1eb6        rabbitmq              "docker-entrypoint.sh"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        4369/tcp, 192.168.168.41:5672->5672/tcp, 5671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 192.168.168.41:15672->15672/tcp   ozcluster01/ozms_rabbitmq_1
8ef3f666a7b9        ozms/config-service   "java -Djava.security"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        192.168.168.42:8888->8888/tcp                                                                   ozcluster02/ozms_config-service_1
```

I find that rabbitmq is start up on machine `ozculster01`,  config-service is start up on machine `ozculster02`.

when docker-compose start `config-service`, there is no `links`, so it can be start up successfully.
but when I  start `eureka-service` on machine `ozculster02`,there is a `links` to `rabbitmq`, but the service `rabbitmq` is on machine `ozculster01`, 
the error occurred.

How could I do to resolve the problem ?
Is that right to use `network_mode: "bridge"`  in Docker Swarm cluster ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem myself.

In swarm mode, docker containers can't contact another container with network_mode:bridge.

In swarm mode, one must use `network_mode : overlay`.  Overlay is used by default if you are using compose-file formate version 2.

see more detail : 
 [Setting up a Docker Swarm with network overlay](http://cloudsuite.ch/swarm/)

With `overlay` mode , docker-compose.yml file do not need the config `likns` , Containers can contact another container with `${service_name_in_composeFile}`

Example:

I can enter into the container `config-service`  , and `$ ping eureka-service`, and it works fine!

this is my compose-file.yml :

```
version: '2'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    ports:
     - "5672:5672"
     - "15672:15672"
  config-service:
    image: ozms/config-service
    ports:
     - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
     - ~/ozms/configs:/var/tmp/
     - ~/ozms/log:/log
    labels:
     - "affinity:image==ozms/config-service"
  eureka-service:
    image: ozms/eureka-service
    ports:
    - "8761:8761"
    volumes:
     - ~/ozms/log:/log
    #links:    it is no need  in overlay mode
    # - config-service
    # - rabbitmq
    environment:
     - SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
```